# select library in SAS from SSIS

Tags: ssis, sas, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS to extract some data out of an SAS server.

using this connection setup (SAS IOM Data Provider 9.3)
[image: Settings]
I can get the connection to read the default Library/Shared data folder.

What do I need to change/set to get it to read a different library?

These are the properties of the libraries:
The one on the left is the one I can read, the one on the right is the one I am trying to access.

[image: Libraries]

Comment: can you share your connection string?

Comment: no connection string. I right click on the database in SQL server, select Tasks, then import data, and select `SAS IOM Data Provider 9.3` as the data source.

Comment: I couldn't find that option in SSIS (Visual Studio 2015), do you have a particular plugin?  Seems really useful!  My answer below was tested in SSAS..

Comment: SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3 and 5.1 are installed. As it's a work machine, it's a little difficult to track down exactly which packages are installed

Comment: No worries.  Did my answer below fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your data folder contains *.sas7bdat files then you could use this:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/09/using-sas-as-source-in-ssis.html

Comment: not using sss7bdat files, but trying to import directly from the server

Answer (score 0):

Simply write your SAS libname statement inside the **SAS Workspace Init Script** box, eg as follows:

```
libname YOURLIB "/your/path/to/sas/datasets" access=readonly;
```

[image: showing a libname statement inside the attribute box]

More info: http://support.sas.com/kb/33/037.html

Comment: still gives the same data as before

Comment: does your libname statement connect succesfully in Enterprise Guide?

Comment: Also you haven't provided your metadata server name (SAS Metadata Location box, you can find it in your connection profile) or your Repository name (most likely `Foundation`).  Let us know if this helps..

Comment: also be sure to use the same user (usws4vn) when testing your libname statement, as well as the same environment (as per metadata server name)